# JSDoc class fields type override

Tags: javascript, class, jsdoc, typing

Using JavaScript's latest class syntax, I have a class `A`, and it has a public field which is an Area object:

```js
class Area {
   /** @type {number} */
   left;
   /** @type {number} */
   top;
   /** @type {number} */
   width;
   /** @type {number} */
   height;
}

class A {
   /** @type {Area} */
   area;
}
```

Now, I have a class `Square` extending class `Area`, and another class `B` extending class `A`.
How can I state in JSDoc to re-define the type of `B.area` as a `Square` object, without re-declaring it?

```js
class Square extends Area {
}

class B extends A {
   /** @type {Square} */
   area;  // <-- I want to remove this line of declaration, but to keep the new typing notation.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with [`@template`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#template) and [`@extends`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-augments.html). This would be the result:

```js
class Area {
  /** @type {number} */
  left;
  /** @type {number} */
  top;
  /** @type {number} */
  width;
  /** @type {number} */
  height;
}

/**
 * @template {Area} T
 */
class A {
  /** @type {T} */
  area;
}

class Square extends Area {
}

/**
 * @extends {A<Square>}
 */
class B extends A {
}
```

[image]